# Media folder out of web server root hierarchy

Tags: wamp

I want to have an offline website (no intention to make it available outside the LAN), to handle several pictures in my user picture folder (and they have to stay where they are), but the thing is that I dont know if I can access them from WAMP, as it's outside the folder hierarchy.

Also thought about another solution that maybe exists some webserver for PHP, like what SQLite is for SQL, lightweight standalone program that doesn't need any installation, and that can be placed anywhere.

Thanks in advance, 
any help would be very apreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to can go about this:

- Use Mod_Rewrite to direct URLs from something like '/pictures' to the location of the pictures, see
  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html
- Change the document root of the apache server in httpd.conf to the location of the pictures (probably not what you want)
- Add another virtual server to apache and set its document root to the location of the pictures
  (again, probably not what you want but thought I'd suggest it)
- Add a symbolic link, not quite sure how it would work (if at all) in Windows but again, something you can look at